# Check certain columns in list of paths and change their data type?

Tags: python, pandas

In a list of csv files (full paths) I want to check certain columns that exist only in about one dataset but I don't know which so I want to check:

If the columns '`DEC_DATE`' and '`KYR_DATE`' found, they should be changed to date type.

Code:

```
for i in li:  #list with paths of csv's
  df = pd.read_csv(i)
  if df['DEC_DATE]: # if csv that has DEC_DATE column found, turn it to date type.
      df['DEC_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DEC_DATE']) # same for the other column
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are getting `KeyError` because you can't access a columns that doesn't exist. You should use `in` and `df.columns` instead:

```
for i in li:  #list with paths of csv's
    df = pd.read_csv(i)
    if 'DEC_DATE' in df.columns:
        df['DEC_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DEC_DATE'])
```

If there are only two columns, you can use two explicit ifs to obtain the full result you want:

```
for i in li: 
    df = pd.read_csv(i)
    if 'DEC_DATE' in df.columns:
        df['DEC_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DEC_DATE'])                
    if 'KYR_DATE' in df.columns:
        df['KYR_DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['KYR_DATE'])
```

Comment: Can you add also how to apply to the other column too?Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check `converters` in `read_csv`

```
pd.read_csv('Temp.csv',converters={'DEC_DATE':pd.to_datetime})
```

Comment: Will this handle the fact that the column may not exist in the dataframe?

Comment: @JulianPeller yes

Comment: Nice, then this is the correct solution from my point of view.